ring A, Nil(A) = R(A), Nil($\frac A p$)= R($\frac A p$)
Let A be a commutative associative ring with unity. Give an example of a ring A, such as  that Nil(A) = R(A), but for the prime ideal factor A/p is fulfilled  Nil($\frac A p$)= R($\frac A p$).
P.S. 1. Recall that the Jacobson radical R(A) is the intersection
of all maximal ideals of the ring A, and the nilradical Nil(A) is equal to
the intersection of all prime ideals in A.
I will be grateful for any hints.
P.S. 2. I have solved a couple of problems for statements about the ideals of rings (f.e "Prove that x ∈ J(A) is equivalent
to the fact that 1−xy is an invertible element for all y ∈ A."), but intuitively I do not know how to reason in this problem. Tell me, what will help you understand the logic of reasoning in such tasks?
(There is a small section about these types of radicals in Lang's textbook)

Please do not answer in the comments, @Functor.

What does but for the prime ideal factor A/p is fulfilled  Nil($\frac A p$)= R($\frac A p$). mean?  From the context it seems like one would expect some sort of negative condition.  Otherwise $R$ some field seems to be an example...

@
rschwieb, in other words "ring A, such as  that Nil(A) = R(A), but for the prime ideal factor A/p is
$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{fulfilled}$ the following holds: Nil($\frac A p$)= R($\frac A p$)."
